# Close menu when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an off-canvas menu that flies out when a toggle-button is clicked - so far so good. All menu links share the same class name (in this case .nav-link). I need the menu to close when any of the links are clicked, I think have selected them all and I think I have to loop through an array of the selection but I'm unsure implement it. Right now nothing happens when a link is clicked.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">articles</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">tags</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">links</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">archive</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
.nav-list {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 3.2em;
    padding: 0;
    background: #777;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .5, 1);
}
```

My JS:

```
const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle')
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')

navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-open')
})

navLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.remove('nav-open')
})
```

Comment: please share you relevant code/css to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Thanks, it wors perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add an event listener to a collection of nodes (`querySelectorAll` 
 for `.nav-link` vs `querySelector` for `.nav-toggle`). You can either iterate over the collection and add your `click` event listener to each item or simply listen to the parent element of the `.nav-link`s:

```js
const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle')
// replace this with something more sensible
const navLinkParent = document.querySelector('.nav-link').parentElement;

navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-open')
})

// this is adding a click listener to ONE element
navLinkParent.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // check if the clicked element matches what you're after
  if (event.target.classList.contains('nav-link')) {
    document.body.classList.remove('nav-open')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**You** must use a loop because `querySelectorAll` returns an array.

```js
const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle')
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')

navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-open')
})

for (var i = 0; i < navLink.length; ++i) {
    navLink[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      if(navToggle.classList.contains('nav-toggle')){
        (navToggle.classList.remove('nav-toggle');
      }
    });
}
```